# laravel 5.2:Adding external php files to laravel

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I added FFmpeg package to laravel5.2 folder and tried to call the FFMpeg class from controller.

It asked for namespace and use method to connect to the FFMpeg class file.my problem is like FFMpeg contains multiple php files and classes defined in it 'each one is related to one another, so do i need to define namespace for every files inside FFMPEG.

steps I did;
1.use App\Http\Controllers\FFMpeg\FFMpeg; using this i connected to FFMpeg class
2.FFMpeg.php contains method to call FFProbe() which is in another file
it works only if i use use App\Http\Controllers\FFMpeg\FFProbe in FFMpeg file.

how can we define namespace for every files? or how to do instead? 
Iam new to laravel ,can anyone please suggest solution for this?

Thanks.!

Comment: Why dont you use this library? https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Comment: yes,this what i used.! FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(); calls a class from there on one by one class is automatically executed and asking to define proper namespace. if not provided i get this following error                                Class 'App\Http\Controllers\FFMpeg' not found

Answer (score 1):

Why not use composer and have it auto load the classes?

```
composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg
```

Just add this at the top of your controller

```
use FFMpeg\FFMpeg
```

And instantiate the object like this

```
$ffmpeg = new FFMpeg::create()
```

If you are adding directly to the App\http\controllers folder, you have to convert all the classes in the package to that namespace. Let composer do the heavy lifting...that is what it is made for

Comment: Thanks,now i get this error RuntimeException in OptionsTester.php line 49:
Your FFProbe version is too old and does not support `-help` option, please upgrade.

Comment: This must be related to the package itself, but it is loading the library just fine now however seeing as you are getting a FFMpeg error. Unfortunately, I don't use FFMpeg so I am unsure what that error means.